# I’ve been trying to understand this sentence: かもしれないと思って。

Tags: particles, particle-って

I checked the translation of かもしれないと思って。
It is "I thought it might be".

As far as I know, the 思って is te form of 思う and is used to show a continuation of action, and the past tense form of 思う is 思った.

Why did the speaker use 思って instead of 思った to show past tense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any further context, ending a sentence like this with the ～て form is kind of like an ellipsis (`...`); like the speaker had a follow-up thought, but just trails off.

> [籤]{くじ}に当たるかもしれないと思って。→　I thought I might win the lottery...  (Follow-up thought could be "So I bought a ticket", "So I already bought a new car", "But obviously I didn't", etc.)

Comment: Thank you very much